# How to Create Box Plot Chart Using ASP.net, C# or Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net, charts

does anyone know how could I create Box Plot Chart using either ASP.net, C# or JavaScript?

This is what I found online but I am not sure on how to apply it to my case:

Code:

```
List<String> xValue = new List<String> { "Ala (A)", "Arg (R)", "Asn (N)", "Asp (D)", "Cys (C)", "Gln (Q)", "Glu (E)", "Gly (G)", "His (H)", "Ile (I)", "Leu (L)", "Lys (K)", "Met (M)", "Phe (F)", "Pro (P)", "Ser (S)", "Thr (T)", "Trp (W)", "Tyr (Y)", "Val (V)", "Pyl (O)", "Sec (U)" };
    Chart Chart = new Chart();
    Chart.chart_main.Series.Clear();
    Chart.chart_main.Series.Add("BoxPlotSeries");
    for (Int32 i = 0; i < xValue.Count; i++)
    {
        Chart.chart_main.Series.Add(xValue[i]); 
    }

    for (Int32 i = 0; i < DYL; i++)
    {
        if (Data[i, 0] == null) break;
        Chart.chart_main.Series[xValue[0]].Points.AddY(boxplot_helper(i, Dataslots[0]));
        Chart.chart_main.Series[xValue[1]].Points.AddY(boxplot_helper(i, Dataslots[1]));
        Chart.chart_main.Series[xValue[2]].Points.AddY(boxplot_helper(i, Dataslots[2]));
        Chart.chart_main.Series[xValue[3]].Points.AddY(boxplot_helper(i, Dataslots[3]));
        Chart.chart_main.Series[xValue[4]].Points.AddY(boxplot_helper(i, Dataslots[4]));
        Chart.chart_main.Series[xValue[5]].Points.AddY(boxplot_helper(i, Dataslots[5]));
        Chart.chart_main.Series[xValue[6]].Points.AddY(boxplot_helper(i, Dataslots[6]));
        Chart.chart_main.Series[xValue[7]].Points.AddY(boxplot_helper(i, Dataslots[7]));
        Chart.chart_main.Series[xValue[8]].Points.AddY(boxplot_helper(i, Dataslots[8]));
        Chart.chart_main.Series[xValue[9]].Points.AddY(boxplot_helper(i, Dataslots[9]));
        Chart.chart_main.Series[xValue[10]].Points.AddY(boxplot_helper(i, Dataslots[10]));
        Chart.chart_main.Series[xValue[11]].Points.AddY(boxplot_helper(i, Dataslots[11]));
        Chart.chart_main.Series[xValue[12]].Points.AddY(boxplot_helper(i, Dataslots[12]));
        Chart.chart_main.Series[xValue[13]].Points.AddY(boxplot_helper(i, Dataslots[13]));
        Chart.chart_main.Series[xValue[14]].Points.AddY(boxplot_helper(i, Dataslots[14]));
        Chart.chart_main.Series[xValue[15]].Points.AddY(boxplot_helper(i, Dataslots[15]));
        Chart.chart_main.Series[xValue[16]].Points.AddY(boxplot_helper(i, Dataslots[16]));
        Chart.chart_main.Series[xValue[17]].Points.AddY(boxplot_helper(i, Dataslots[17]));
        Chart.chart_main.Series[xValue[18]].Points.AddY(boxplot_helper(i, Dataslots[18]));
        Chart.chart_main.Series[xValue[19]].Points.AddY(boxplot_helper(i, Dataslots[19]));
        Chart.chart_main.Series[xValue[20]].Points.AddY(boxplot_helper(i, Dataslots[20]));
        Chart.chart_main.Series[xValue[21]].Points.AddY(boxplot_helper(i, Dataslots[21]));     
    }

    Chart.chart_main.Series["BoxPlotSeries"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.BoxPlot;
    Chart.chart_main.Series["BoxPlotSeries"]["BoxPlotSeries"] = xValue[0];

    Chart.chart_main.ChartAreas.Add("BoxPlot");
    Chart.chart_main.Series["BoxPlotSeries"].ChartArea = "BoxPlot";

    Chart.chart_main.Series["BoxPlotSeries"]["BoxPlotWhiskerPercentile"] = "0";
    Chart.chart_main.Series["BoxPlotSeries"]["BoxPlotPercentile"] = "25";
    Chart.chart_main.Series["BoxPlotSeries"]["BoxPlotShowAverage"] = "true";
    Chart.chart_main.Series["BoxPlotSeries"]["BoxPlotShowMedian"] = "true";
    Chart.chart_main.Series["BoxPlotSeries"]["BoxPlotShowUnusualValues"] = "true";
    Chart.chart_main.Series["BoxPlotSeries"]["MaxPixelPointWidth"] = "15";
    Chart.chart_main.Series["BoxPlotSeries"].BorderWidth = 2;
    Chart.Show();

}

private Double boxplot_helper(Int32 i, Int32 slot)
{
    String Santas = Data[i, slot].Replace('.', ',').TrimEnd('%').Trim();
    Double LittleHelper = Convert.ToDouble(Santas);
    return LittleHelper;
```

Appreciate if anyone could help me on this, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an ASP.NET sample:

```
    <asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server" Width="600px">
        <Series>
            <asp:Series Name="Series1" ChartType="BoxPlot" YValuesPerPoint="6">
                <Points>
                    <asp:DataPoint XValue="1" YValues="10,60,20,50,30,40" />
                    <asp:DataPoint XValue="2" YValues="40,90,50,80,60,70" />
                    <asp:DataPoint XValue="3" YValues="20,70,30,60,40,50" />
                </Points>
            </asp:Series>
        </Series>
        <ChartAreas>
            <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">
                <AxisY>
                    <MajorGrid LineColor="DarkGray" LineDashStyle="Dot" />
                    <MajorTickMark LineColor="DarkGray" LineDashStyle="Dot" />
                </AxisY>
                <AxisX>
                    <MajorGrid LineColor="DarkGray" LineDashStyle="Dot" />
                    <MajorTickMark LineColor="DarkGray" LineDashStyle="Dot" />
                </AxisX>
            </asp:ChartArea>
        </ChartAreas>
    </asp:Chart>
```

[image]

You can look for details here: [MSDN - Box Plot Chart](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456709.aspx)

**EDIT:**
You can dynamically bind data like this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyDataCollection data = new MyDataCollection();
        Chart1.Series[0].Points.DataBind(data, "XValue", "LowWhisker,UpWhisker,LowWBox,UpBox,Average,Median", null);
    }

public class MyDataCollection : List<MyData>
{
    public MyDataCollection()
    {
        Add(new MyData { XValue = 1, LowWhisker = 10, UpWhisker = 60, LowWBox = 20, UpBox = 50, Average = 30, Median = 40 });
        Add(new MyData { XValue = 2, LowWhisker = 40, UpWhisker = 90, LowWBox = 50, UpBox = 80, Average = 60, Median = 70 });
        Add(new MyData { XValue = 3, LowWhisker = 20, UpWhisker = 70, LowWBox = 30, UpBox = 60, Average = 40, Median = 50 });
    }
}

public class MyData
{
    public double XValue { get; set; }
    public double LowWhisker { get; set; }
    public double UpWhisker { get; set; }
    public double LowWBox { get; set; }
    public double UpBox { get; set; }
    public double Average { get; set; }
    public double Median { get; set; }
}
```

Whenever you add/remove data to your collection you need to call `DataBind()`.

**EDIT 2:** You can make `XValue` a `string` by modifying `MyData` and `MyDataCollection` accordingly:

[image]

**EDIT 3**: Using a `DataTable`,

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyDataTable dt = new MyDataTable();

        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            Chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(row["Status"], new object[] { row["Min"], row["Max"], row["Avg"], row["Percentile25"], row["Percentile50"], row["Percentile75"] });
    }

public class MyDataTable : DataTable
{
    public MyDataTable()
    {
        Columns.Add("Title", typeof(string));
        Columns.Add("Status", typeof(string));
        Columns.Add("Min", typeof(double));
        Columns.Add("Max", typeof(double));
        Columns.Add("Avg", typeof(double));
        Columns.Add("Percentile25", typeof(double));
        Columns.Add("Percentile50", typeof(double));
        Columns.Add("Percentile75", typeof(double));

        DataRow row = NewRow();
        row["Status"] = "Status 1";
        row["Min"] = 10;
        row["Max"] = 60;
        row["Avg"] = 20;
        row["Percentile25"] = 50;
        row["Percentile50"] = 30;
        row["Percentile75"] = 40;
        Rows.Add(row);

        row = NewRow();
        row["Status"] = "Status 2";
        row["Min"] = 40;
        row["Max"] = 90;
        row["Avg"] = 50;
        row["Percentile25"] = 80;
        row["Percentile50"] = 60;
        row["Percentile75"] = 70;
        Rows.Add(row);

        row = NewRow();
        row["Status"] = "Status 3";
        row["Min"] = 20;
        row["Max"] = 70;
        row["Avg"] = 30;
        row["Percentile25"] = 60;
        row["Percentile50"] = 40;
        row["Percentile75"] = 50;
        Rows.Add(row);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the codes! This is the static way of creating the chart. Do you know how can I create the chart dynamically based on either I bind values from a table in database or to retrieve values from grid view?

Comment: hi jstreet, I have tried your methods by putting the codes inside Page_Load and delete away   <asp:DataPoint XValue="1" YValues="10,60,20,50,30,40" />
                    <asp:DataPoint XValue="2" YValues="40,90,50,80,60,70" />
                    <asp:DataPoint XValue="3" YValues="20,70,30,60,40,50" /> from aspx file but it doesn't work..

Comment: Hi  jstreet, would like to ask how to change DataPoint XValue to be text instead of number?

Comment: Yes, you can have a `string` for `XValue`. Please see updated post.

Comment: Hi jstreet, thanks for your codes. I would like to bind datatable that contains many rows to create box plot chart dynamically, I do not know how to apply the codes you shown into my context. Could you provide me help on this? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @Felicia Soh: hi, all you have to do is to map data from your `DataTable` into `MyDataCollection`. Can you do that?

Comment: Hi jstreet, sorry I have researched quite awhile online but are not sure of how to map data from DataTable to MyDataCollection. Could you please help me on that? I need this urgently..so sorry!

Comment: what are the columns in your data table?

Comment: the columns in my datatable are :
            tg.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("TITLE"));
            tg.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("STATUS"));
            tg.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("MAX"));
            tg.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("MIN"));
            tg.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("AVG"));
            tg.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("PERCENTILE25"));
            tg.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("PERCENTILE50"));
            tg.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("PERCENTILE75"));

Comment: Ok, i'll post a sample using this info as soon as i can.

Comment: I posted some code sample using `DataTable`, please see if it helps.

Comment: hi @jstreet, I faced error when trying to use your codes in my context. So now I have one gridview, where I check whether a value existed in a column of a gridview. If existed, then I will add those rows from gridview that has that value into the datatable. I can do this and then create column chart, but I want is to create box plot chart. The problem occurred when I used your codes and tried to check which row has that value from that column and then add those rows to the datatable. I will show u my codes.

Comment: What is the error you get? Post full stack trace for your error. Why don't you start from a simple working sample solution like the one i provided and then adapt it to your case?

Comment: hi @jstreet, i tried your sample solution but error occurred. This is the error I received: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index.   The error came from this line: Line 40:                 Chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(row["Status"], new object[] { row["Min"], row["Max"], row["Avg"], row["Percentile25"], row["Percentile50"], row["Percentile75"] });

Comment: Line 40? There's not 40 lines in my code... If you just drop my sample code in the middle of your code, chances are it is not going to work... you have to understand the code and make adjustments for your case. Index out of range means you're trying to access something that does not exist...

Comment: hi @jstreet, thanks I have solved this issue! Thanks a lot for your help!! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an error in the 3rd example, Edit 3 Using a DataTable. The error
is in the order of the statistical values inserted in the object array.

I believe following should be the statement, similar to Edit 1 & Edit 2 examples, instead of what is being used.

Chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(row["Status"], new object[] { row["Min"], row["Max"], row["Percentile25"], row["Percentile75"], row["Avg"], row["Percentile50"]});